# iText7 tabs with right align text

Tags: itext7

I can see that iText7 will render tabs correctly when the text is left aligned but for right aligned text the tab thinks the text is left aligned and renders as if the text is left aligned.

Does anyone know if this is a problem caused by something I'm missing or is it a limitation/bug in iText7?

Update:

```
@Test
public void shouldTabFromTheRightWhenTextAlignIsFromTheRight() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String outFileName = destinationFolder + "tabRightAlignedTextTest.pdf";
    String cmpFileName = sourceFolder + "cmp_tabRightAlignedTextTest.pdf";

    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(file);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.setFontColor(Color.GREEN);
    p.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);
    p.add(new Text("text out of page"));
    p.add(new Tab());
    p.add(new Text(" bounds after right tab stop:"));
    doc.add(p);

    p = new Paragraph();
    p.setFontColor(Color.GREEN);
    p.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);
    p.add(new Text("text out of"));
    p.add(new Tab());
    p.add(new Text(" page bounds after right tab stop:"));
    doc.add(p);

    p = new Paragraph();
    p.setFontColor(Color.GREEN);
    p.add(new Text("text out of page"));
    p.add(new Tab());
    p.add(new Text(" bounds after right tab stop:"));
    doc.add(p);

    p = new Paragraph();
    p.setFontColor(Color.GREEN);
    p.add(new Text("text out of"));
    p.add(new Tab());
    p.add(new Text(" page bounds after right tab stop:"));
    doc.add(p);

    doc.close();

    Assert.assertNull(new CompareTool().compareByContent(outFileName, cmpFileName, destinationFolder, "diff"));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example that shows that behavior. If you look at figure  3.4 in the [official documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-3-using-ileafelement-implementations) or if you look at the example for that chapter, you will see that the text is aligned as expected: [jekyll_hyde_tabs3.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/raw/develop/publications/highlevel/cmpfiles/chapter03/cmp_jekyll_hyde_tabs3.pdf)

Comment: I took the develop and master branch. Added this test and got this result.

Comment: I can now see what the iText example does. This is creating left aligned text that is pulled to right aligned tab. The desired functionality is to have the tab calculations reversed when the text is right aligned

Comment: The desired behavior you describe isn't the behavior of tabs. The desired behavior you describe is the behavior you get with tables. Why are you using tabs when you should be using tables?

Comment: Today I use tables for this however it just means putting tables within tables for what I want. So I have a table 4x4. The first column is left aligned and the rest are right aligned. But the final column has a number and percent. 155   (58%). I want all rows to have the text aligned on the final column. Tables works for now but its just move convince to use tabs if that was possible. After looking at word I now see this behaviour there too. I'll move on and use tables :)